# Can not interact with ionic component in an Angular Ionic App with jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jestjs

as already mentioned I`m not able to interact with ionic components. I try to write unit test and to mock some methods just to check if they have been called. But it does not works. Here is the output for the rendered html:

```
    <body>
  <div
    id="root0"
    ng-version="16.1.1"
  >
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>
          while
        </ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-label>
                   Searchvalue: 
                </ion-label>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-text>
                  3yJ_;I\k](
                </ion-text>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </p>
        <p>
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-label>
                   Category: 
                </ion-label>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-text>
                  !x6YwG\WmW
                </ion-text>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </p>
        <p>
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-label>
                   Location: 
                </ion-label>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-text>
                  New Lukasland
                </ion-text>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </p>
        <p>
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-label>
                   Radius: 
                </ion-label>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-text>
                  1
                </ion-text>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </p>
        <div
          class="my-5"
        >
          <ion-toggle
            ng-reflect-checked="true"
          >
            Email
          </ion-toggle>
        </div>
        <div
          class="mb-5"
        >
          <ion-toggle
            data-testid="toggle-enable-notifications"
            ng-reflect-checked="false"
          >
            Notiications
          </ion-toggle>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ion-button
            color="danger"
            id="delete-search-m"
            ng-reflect-color="danger"
          >
            Delete
          </ion-button>
          <ion-button
            id="edit-search-m"
          >
            Rename
          </ion-button>
        </div>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-alert
      data-testid="delete-alert"
      header="Delete saved search"
      message="Are your sure, that you want to delete your saved search?"
      ng-reflect-buttons="[object Object],[object Object"
      ng-reflect-header="Delete saved search"
      ng-reflect-message="Are your sure, that you want t"
      ng-reflect-trigger="delete-search-m"
    />
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is my current implementation with jest

```
    let mockSearch = getMockSearches(1)[0];
const spyEnableNotifications = jest.fn()
const { getByTestId, container } = await render(SavedSearchesCardComponent, {
  componentProperties: {
    search: mockSearch,
    changeEnableNotifications: {
      emit: spyEnableNotifications
    } as any
  },
  providers: [provideStore()],
  imports: [IonicModule],
});

const toggle = getByTestId('toggle-enable-notifications')
console.log(toggle)
// Act
// @ts-ignore
await userEvent.click(toggle)
// Assert
screen.debug()
expect(spyEnableNotifications).toHaveBeenCalled()
expect(spyEnableNotifications).toHaveBeenCalledWith(!mockSearch.enableNotifications)
```

I am using Angular 16, Ionic 7 and also the latest version of jest and angular testing library.